# Can I define log4j rules so that info and fatal (only) show on console and warn and higher gets logged to a file?

Tags: java, log4j

I've got the following log4j.properties file set up so that info events appear on the console and everything above warning appears in a log file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%m

log4j.logger.org.company.package=warn, file
log4j.additivity.org.company.package=false
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=SmartBay.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

I'd like to also display fatal events on the console so that an administrator can readily see that the application has terminated, and then look at the log file for details. Is there any way I can accomplish this cleanly? I tried adding the following to the file, but depending on where I paced it, it would either stop errors from sh

```
log4j.logger.net.compusult.sb_SensorClient_v1_0_0=fatal, console2, file
log4j.appender.console2=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console2.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p: %m
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple appenders in log file and assign different log levels to it.

```
log4j.rootLogger = consoleAppender, fileAppender
#Console Appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%m

# Console appender to fatal
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.Threshhold = FATAL

#File Appender
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=SmartPay.log
 .
 .
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# File Appender to warn
log4j.appender.fileAppender.Threshold = WARN
```